# Ratchet Server vs Long Polling

Tags: php, ajax, websocket, ratchet

I am developing a website which has a chat feature and requires instant notifications when a user receives a new message.  I am trying to decide whether to use a Ratchet server or implement a long polling system with AJAX.  I have currently implemented a basic Pub/Sub Ratchet server which works fine when delivering notifications while a user remains on the "Chat" page on my site.  My problem here is that the connection is closed whenever the user moves to any other page, and I need to re-create a connection to the server.  I am aware that there are possible solutions such as having the websocket connection exist within an IFrame which is always displayed, however I do not want to go down this path if I do not have to.  Would a better approach be to implement long polling with AJAX?  I am concerned that if I continually re-create a users connection to the Ratchet server whenever they change pages within the site, it will add too much overhead when the site is under heavy usage (thousands of users at a time).  Does anyone have experience in this area with Ratchet servers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a disclaimer I'm not very knowledgeable in this area, but you should not use long polling. You say you need "instant notifications," which means with AJAX you would have to be making very frequent requests, whereas with websockets you simply establish the connection and wait for data.

I haven't done any sort of testing, but it seems like establishing and maintaining one websocket connection per browser tab would be less overhead than constantly making AJAX requests, not to mention that you can't truly have "instant notifications" with AJAX because you'd have to make requests at an unsustainable rate to achieve that.

So open a websocket connection for each browser tab the user has. If they open a new tab, or browse to a different page, simply open the connection again.